# How send email from command line specifying the email subject and using postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, command-line-interface, sendmail

I installed *Postfix*, and get the `/usr/lib/sendmail` binary. What I want is send an email alo

```
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "EMAIL_BODY" | /usr/lib/sendmail -s "EMAIL_SUBJECT" destination@adress.com
```

But the `-s` option is not recognized. How send email from command line specifying the email subject and using postfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [mailx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx):

```
echo "hello world" | mailx -s "Test from CLI" recipient@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, ones of the Ubuntu packages to get a *mailx* command working is: *bsd-mailx*